# React Web App Deployed on GH Pages shows Only Background - shows nothing else

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have made a React web app: https://github.com/Hamsterland/mal-rewrite

It's `gh-pages` contains the static files. However, if you navigate to https://hamsterland.github.io/mal-rewrite/ the screen is just black.

I'm not sure what's wrong.

package.json important bits:

```json
"homepage": "https://Hamsterland.github.io/mal-rewrite",
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I access my media fine, https://hamsterland.github.io/mal-rewrite/static/media/background.db542337.png works for example.